# how to check if letter is not in the alphabet in twig

Tags: php, regex, twig

I have the following:

```
{% if shop.username|first|lower == letter%}
```

how do I check if `shop.username | first | lower`is  non-alphabet (not A-Za-Z) is it possible in twig?

Comment: You could use `!ctype_alpha($variable)` if that help's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match against a regular expression:

```
{% if shop.username matches '/^[a-z]/i' %}
```

You can invert the character class to `[^a-z]` to match for "does not start with a letter".

Comment: i tried that and it doesn't work, it still matches those that starts with A

Comment: Did you try with `[^a-z]`?

Comment: you mean remove the /i

Comment: No, I mean `'/^[^a-z]/i'`.

Comment: That makes no sense unless `shop.username` is empty.